# Max Heapifying a Binary Tree via sorting an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, heap

Suppose I have a pointer to a binary tree.
Would I be correct in assuming that converting the binary tree to an array, sorting that array in order of greatest to smallest value, and then converting the sorted array back into a binary tree is a potential way of max-heapifying?
I know it may not be the most efficient, but I just was wondering if this works.

Steps:

1.) Convert the inputted binary tree to an array.
2.) Sort the array from greatest to least values.
3.) Convert the sorted array back into a binary tree.

Comment: Yes, I believe that would work. A binary search tree actually has stronger ordering than a heap (hence building a heap is cheaper on average).

Comment: An array is already a representation of a complete binary tree, so no conversion is needed. When the array is sorted it represents a heap.

Comment: But why sort the array (an O(n log n) operation, at best) when you can heapify it in O(n). Your second should be "heapify the array." But, sure, if you want to spend the extra time sorting, knock yourself out. I'm kind of curious to know what prompted this question.